# Class reuse with JAXB bindings don't honour SimpleTypes

Tags: jaxb, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I'm trying to reuse classes that are already compiled and available. This looks to be achievable by declaring bindings to the pre-existing classes as per example bindings extract below:-

```
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="MyExample.xsd">
    <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='MySimpleType']">
        <jaxb:class ref="com.example.MySimpleType" />
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='MyComplexType']">
        <jaxb:class ref="com.example.MyComplexType" />
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

The problem is that whilst complex types work just fine, the simple types are ignored and still generated....

I've tried a variety of different notations (e.g. scd) with no success on the Simple Types.

Any ideas or help very welcome....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the generated class you are trying to reference is an enumeration (i.e. it implements `javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlEnum`), then you need to use:

```
jaxb:typesafeEnumClass
```

instead of

```
jaxb:class
```

in the bindings.