# JAXB :: xjc 2.2 not recognizing bindings for simple types

Tags: jaxb, xjc

I have a bunch of **xsd** schemas some of which import others. So, whenever I invoke [xjc](https://jaxb.java.net/2.2.4/docs/xjcTask.html) (either the Ant task or the command line tool) on some **xsd** files which import others, I pass along a bindings file to ensure that the imported classes are not generated again (since they have already been generated for the "upstread" schema). This solution is described in [this SO post (answer by Blaise Doughan)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869547/jaxb-creating-modules-for-reuse/5872659#5872659).

While this approach does work for **xsd:complexType** types, it does not seem to work for **xsd:simpleType** types. Here's a narrowed down example to demonstrate this. Say we have two dead-simple schemas one importing the other:

```
a.xsd   ---import-->  b.xsd
```

Files are:

## a.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://example.a" 
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

   <xs:import namespace="http://example.b"
              schemaLocation="b.xsd"/>

</xs:schema>
```

## b.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://example.b" 
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           xmlns:b="http://example.b" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified">

   <xs:simpleType name="ResourceType">
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
         <xs:enumeration value="alpha"/>
         <xs:enumeration value="beta"/>
      </xs:restriction>
   </xs:simpleType>

   <xs:complexType name="ResourceType2">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="a" type="xs:integer"/>
        </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

So basically **a.xsd** does nothing and only imports **b.xsd**. when one invokes **xjc** on **a.xsd** as follows:

```
xjc -d output -p example.a -npa a.xsd
```

you get:

```
output/
└── example
    └── a
        ├── ObjectFactory.java
        ├── ResourceType2.java
        └── ResourceType.java
```

So files were generated for the imported schema. Since we don't want that, we define the following bindings file to pass along:

## imported-bindings.xml

```
<jxb:bindings 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    version="2.1">

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="b.xsd">
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='ResourceType']">
            <jxb:class ref="example.b.ResourceType"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='ResourceType2']">
            <jxb:class ref="example.b.ResourceType2"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

**HOWEVER** when we invoke again **xjc** on **a.xsd** with the **-b** option as below:

```
xjc -d output -p a.example a.xsd -b imported-bindings.xml
```

we see the following in the output directory:

```
output/
└── example
    └── a
        ├── ObjectFactory.java
        └── ResourceType.java
```

That is, generation of the **xsd:complexType** "ResourceType2" was indeed suppressed, but **xjc** went ahead and generated code for the imported **xsd:simpleType** "ResourceType". Any ideas?

**UPDATE**
I still haven't gotten this to work except by a workaround using automatically generated **episode** files

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15656803/class-reuse-with-jaxb-bindings-dont-honour-simpletypes Work fine for me.